# Will Cloudfare Cache bridge Heroku free-tier idle time?

Tags: heroku, caching, https, cloudflare

I have a simple static website on Heroku free-tier. Heroku puts servers on the sleep after some time of no traffic, and then the first user coming again needs to wait some ˜30 seconds till the server boots again.

My question is whether having the website cached by Cloudflare would bridge this 30 second waiting time, please?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Cloudflare respects the origin web server’s cache headers unless overridden via an Edge Cache TTL Page Rule.

You might be able to instruct Cloudflare to cache all of your static assets by making Your server respond with the right header. You will be able to clear Cloudflare’s cache from their dashboard every time you update your website but the website might still be cached forever on your past visitors' browsers.

You can bypass this problem by making your server respond with reasonable cache headers and instructing Cloudflare to cache it forever using their custom edge cache page rule (and clearing the cache manually every time you update your website)

Note that if your website uses non-static requests (I.e login, signup, filling forms) this won’t work at all